# AlertDialog in a function which has a return value

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have written a function which has a return value of type int,and in this function I need to pop up an AlertDialog with two buttons. When the "Yes" button is clicked,the function return 0,and "No" button return -1.

```
public int Func(){
    final AlertDialog d=new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).setTitle("Warning").setCancelable(false).setMessage
                       (alert)
                       .setPositiveButton("Yes",mListener).setNegativeButton("No",mListener).create();
                       d.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
                       d.show();
   if(mWhich.getWhich()==-1)   //the "yes" button was clicked
       return 0;
   else                        //the "no"  button was clicked
       return -1;
}
```

mWhich is a class used to record the user choices

```
private DialogInterface.OnClickListener mListener =
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    mWhich.setWhich(which);
                             }
            };
```

Now the problem is the code

```
if(mWhich.getWhich()==-1)
       return 0;
   else
       return -1;
```

was executed before the user click the yes or no button,how should I do??

Comment: what you are getting when Yes or No button is pressed when running current code

Comment: take an integer variable globally and assign value in it(0 or 1) and later check value of it.

Answer (score 2):

As I understood, your code looks similar to

```
// some code
int result = Func();
DoSmthWithResult(result);
// some code
```

Your `Func` is running on the UI thread, so after you create dialog it continues executing and returns initial value of `mWich`. You should call `DoSmthWithResult` from `onClickListener` instead:

```
private DialogInterface.OnClickListener mListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        DoSmthWithresult(which == -1 ? 0 : -1);
    }
};
```

Now `DoSmthWithResult` will be executed after user pressed "yes" or "no" button.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I cannot put DoSmthWithresult(which == -1 ? 0 : -1); in the onClick Function,because I called Func() in several places, and the later operation is different in these places.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible the way you do it because `Func()` would probably finish executing before the user clicks either of the buttons. It would be impossible to change the return value of the method after it finished executing.

Since you are already storing `which` using `mWhich.setWhich(which);`. You can read the value later using another function.

```
private DialogInterface.OnClickListener mListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        mWhich.setWhich(which);
    }
};

public void showDialog() {
    final AlertDialog d = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).setTitle("Warning")
            .setCancelable(false).setMessage(alert).setPositiveButton("Yes", mListener)
            .setNegativeButton("No", mListener).create();
    d.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
    d.show();
}

public int func() {
    if (mWhich.getWhich() == -1)
        // the "yes" button was clicked
        return 0;
    else
        // the "no" button was clicked
        return -1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I donot think it worked. Because I want to read the value once the button is clicked

Comment: @zhouqihui What exactly are you trying to accomplish? If you can tell us, I think the community could come up with better solutions.

Comment: I want to decide the return value of Func() based on the user choice of "Yes" or "No" . Both the operation of poping up AlertDialog and the decision based on user choices are in Func(). In Func()，I first do something and get a result,then I present that result to the user on a AlertDialog with button "Yes" and "No". When the user click "Yes",Func() returns 0, "No" returns -1.

Comment: could you provide me with the part of the code where Func() is used?

Answer (score 0):

While its certainly the android way to use a listener and start a new call hierarchy on click (as Yuriy and Binoy proposed), it can be necessary to get a blocking dialog. I realized that by starting a new Thread with own looper that displays the dialog. That way the ui thread is free to run, but does not result in an ANR.

Answer (score 0):

I've needed same functionality to show confirmation dialogs, and here is my workaround:

Your `Func()` can be like my `messageDialog()` on this way:

```
    public static void messageDialog( Context context, String title, String bt_ok, String bt_cancel, final Runnable if_ok, final Runnable if_cancel ) {

        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

        alert.setTitle( title );

        alert.setPositiveButton( bt_ok.toUpperCase(),
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                        if(if_ok!=null) if_ok.run();

                    }
                });
        alert.setNegativeButton( bt_cancel.toUpperCase(),
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                        if(if_cancel!=null) if_cancel.run();

                    }
                });

        alert.show();

    }
```

and call `messageDialog()` on this way:

```
    Runnable ifTrue = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //put here your YES onClick stuff
        }
    };

    String msg = "Do you really want to do this?";

    ALITEC.Dialogs.messageDialog( this, msg, "Yes", "No", ifTrue, null);
```

On NO button click, I wasn't do nothing... but if you want:

```
    Runnable ifFalse = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //put here your NO onClick stuff
        }
    };
```

and then call

> messageDialog( this, msg, "Yes", "No", ifTrue, ifFalse );

instead

> messageDialog( this, msg, "Yes", "No", ifTrue, null );

That's all!

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

Add Handler which processes the message it receives

```
 public static boolean areYouSure(Context context, String message){

    final boolean[] result = new boolean[1];
    final Handler handler = new Handler()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message mesg)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    };

    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    alert.setTitle(message);

    alert.setPositiveButton("OK", (dialog, whichButton) -> {
        //What ever you want to do with the value
        result[0] = true;
        handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage());
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", (dialog, whichButton) -> {
        // what ever you want to do with No option.
        result[0] = false;
        handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage());
    });

    alert.show();

    try{ Looper.loop(); }
    catch(RuntimeException e){}

    return result[0];
}
```